# <br /> is read as <br></br> in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, firefox

I am using `<br />` and its working correctly in chrome and IE as expected but in firefox the result is weird. When i saw the code in firefox, its replacing the `<br />` with `<br ></br>`.

I also read somewhere that the alternative syntax `<br></br>` allowed by XML gives uncertain results in many existing user agents.

If I replace `<br />` with `<br>`, its works fine in chrome and IE but firefox again replaces it with `<br ></br>` and gives extra margin.

what's the fix for this problem in firefox?

Comment: what doctype are you using?

Comment: What's your doctype set to? `<br />` is XHTML, `<br>` is HTML. If you fall back to quirks mode, well, have fun with that :P

Comment: What content-type are you using? `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: "When i saw the code in firefox" Saw it where...?

Comment: "<br></br> ... gives uncertain results" No, it gives the same result in every mainstream browser around today, including old ones like IE6.

Comment: What problem? What is the actual problem you are facing? Please show a demo document where `<br />` “gives extra margin” and identify what you regard as extra margin.

Answer (score 1):

Putting

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>This is<br />a test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in a text file with the "html" extension, opening the file in Firefox, and checking the source view showed `<br />` as expected. Firefox only shows `<br ></br>` when using the Inspector view, as far as I can tell, which is likely a result of standardizing how tags are displayed in that view as using `<br>` instead of `<br />` also produces `<br ></br>` in it.

Comment: The DOM API actually returns `<br></br>` — this is more than just the inspector view, this is the way Firefox encodes a `br` DOM node to HTML.